# How can I add a shape into a table so it retains the shape properties?

Tags: microsoft-word, shapes, table-styles

When inserting a shape to a table, the shape isn't really inside the table at all. It just floats independently of the table.

If I cut the shape and paste it into the table, then it's actually IN the table. Only problem is, Word converts the shape into a picture; which is really not what I want at all.

How can I add a shape into a table so it retains the shape properties?

Answer (score 3):

Shapes don't know what to do unless we tell them. All you need to do is change the position to `In Line with text` from the format tab.

[image]